# how do I replace part of a string after a specific substring

Tags: python, arrays, string, replace

using python and selenium. I have multiple URLs as strings in a list. however I want to be able to replace a part of the string(end of the string) after a substring in the string.

ive tried replace(). however that only replaces what I state specifically. For instance this link:

https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB

however the numbers after 'sku=' and 'planSku' change as I go through the list of URLS

```
    phonePlanLinksRaw = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'deviceListItem')]/a")

    phonePlanLinks = [] #contains the links to all phones



    for element in phonePlanLinksRaw:
        phonePlanLinks.append(str(element.get_attribute('href')))

    phonePlanLinks.pop() #removes bring your own phone

# prints all links
    numLink = 1
    for element in range(len(phonePlanLinks)):
        print("phone " + str(numLink) + " : " + phonePlanLinks[element])
        numLink += 1
```

i want to be able to swap substrings in an out of urls after a certain point in a string.

For instance:
https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB

'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=' stays

then I want to be able to attach my own substring after 'planSku'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use .split() with your keyword as the separator and then just concatenate the keyword and value to the first part:

```
url = "https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB"
keyword  ="planSku="
newValue ="MyValue"
newUrl   =url.split(keyword,1)[0]+keyword+newValue
print(newUrl)
# https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=MyValue
```

You could also use a regular expression substitution (re module)

```
import re
newUrl = re.sub(f"({keyword})(.*)",f"\\g<1>{newValue}",url)
```

But you will have to be careful with special characters in your keyword and newValue (which you can escape using re.escape() if need be).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL as a string like this:

```
url = 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Maxsku={}'
```

Inside the for, you can do something like this:

```
for element in phonePlanLinksRaw:
    urlnew = url.format(element)
```

And then, the values in your list will be inputed to the string. The '{}' will be fitted by the 'element' value.